# loop through files and execute jar with each file passed as arguments

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

```
    cd /D "%~dp0"
@echo off
for %%f in ("Z:\java_projects\IDS\trunk\deployment\config\client\%1\Documentation\MappingEngine_*.xml")
do(
    echo %%~nxf
    java -jar EngineUtil.jar 192.67.64.172 %%f
)
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. 
I want to create a batch file to loop through a set files from a directory and run a jar file with one file at a time passed as argument. 
The directory is dependent on a command line parameter.

Comment: a)  the `do` has to be on the same line as `for`. b) there has to be a space between `do` and `(`.

Comment: It is great that you have posted the code you are trying. It would be helpful if you add in what way it is not working as you expect. Copy and paste exact error messages when possible.

Comment: @Liturgist The error said wrong syntax for command or something.

Comment: @Stephan I will try it out and see how it goes :) Thanks!

Comment: @Stephan Thanks, That was just what I needed! It works as expected :)